# Cannot GET / on localhost:8080 when using npm run hot

Tags: npm, vuejs2, laravel-mix

I'm using laravel vuejs spa and would like to use npm run hot so that the browser gets refreshed automatically.

Here is my webpack.mix file

```
const path = require('path')
const mix = require('laravel-mix')
// const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer')

mix.config.vue.esModule = true

mix
  .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .styles([
      'resources/assets/css/app.css',
      'resources/assets/css/style.css'
  ], 'public/css/app.css')

  .sourceMaps()
  .disableNotifications()

if (mix.inProduction()) {
  mix.version()

  mix.extract([
    'vue',
    'vform',
    'axios',
    'vuex',
    'jquery',
    'popper.js',
    'vue-i18n',
    'vue-meta',
    'js-cookie',
    'bootstrap',
    'vue-router',
    'sweetalert2',
    'vuex-router-sync',
    '@fortawesome/fontawesome',
    '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
  ])
}

mix.webpackConfig({
  plugins: [
    // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.vue'],
    alias: {
      '~': path.join(__dirname, './resources/assets/js')
    }
  },
  output: {
    chunkFilename: 'js/[name].[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath: mix.config.hmr ? '//localhost:8080' : '/'
  }
})
```

I configured mysite.com on my localhost and when i visit mysite.com im able to view the site. But it does not get refreshed when i make changes. I followed few articles on the internet and found that it would be on localhost:8080.

Now when i visit to localhost:8080 all i see is a blank page with error Cannot GET /

Does anyone know how to solve this and make the browser refreshed whenever i make changes in my project.